# Error using Firebase AppCheck and Play Integrity in Xiaomi Redmi Note 9S (403 - App attestation failed)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, firebase-app-check, redmi-device

A user of our app is getting the following error when we try to retrieve the Firebase AppCheck token (Play Integrity) to verify their device (in the Login screen):

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed
```

(we got the error logs from Crashlytics)

We call the method `getToken()` as explained at https://rnfirebase.io/app-check/usage (ReactNative + Expo App).

The user is using a Xiaomi Redmi Note 9S device with Android 12 and their OS is not modified (according to Crashlytics).

We have thousands of users using our app from Play Store and the AppCheck token is retrieved without any issue.

What can I do to solve this issue? (the user can't login in the app otherwise)

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @Todd Unfortunately not. We provide users login with email that require AppCheck authentication, and social login (Google, Facebook) that don't require it. So, we advised the user to login using one of the social buttons. I don't know if this issue was solved, but at least I don't remember another user reporting this problem.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this. Shoot, we don't have social logins wired up, so I will keep looking into this.